# syntax for trigger before insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, schema, constraints, mysql-error-1170

Ok, so I [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744926/262852) that this the wrong approach:

```
mysql> 
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_nntp      |
+---------------------+
| articles            |
| newsgroups          |
| newsgroups_articles |
+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe newsgroups;
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| newsgroup | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table newsgroups;
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table      | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                      |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| newsgroups | CREATE TABLE `newsgroups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `newsgroup` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE newsgroups ADD UNIQUE (newsgroup);
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'newsgroup' used in key specification without a key length
mysql>
```

The has should be populated with a [trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11024249/262852)?

Ok, as root I made a trigger as so:

```
mysql> 
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_nntp      |
+---------------------+
| articles            |
| newsgroups          |
| newsgroups_articles |
+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> delimiter |
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER make_hash BEFORE INSERT ON newsgroups
    ->   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    ->       INSERT INTO hash values ('0');
    ->   END;
    -> |
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)

mysql>
```

However, that's just dummy data.  How can I make that trigger actually create the hash?

Comment: 'TRIGGER command denied to user ...' - you should check what privileges your user has and run the create trigger with a different user if necessary.

Comment: @Vatev I'll try as root, but I don't think that's the problem, user java has `USAGE`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should leave your primary key as is.
You can add a hash column

```
ALTER TABLE `newsgroups` ADD COLUMN `hash` CHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

and then populate it with

```
UPDATE newsgroups SET hash = MD5(newsgroup);
```

then remove the duplicates and add your unique constraint.

You can also add `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers to set the `hash` value

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `before_insert_newsgroups` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `newsgroups` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    set new.hash = md5(new.newsgroup);

END
```

Depending on the SQL client you are using you might wan't to [change the DELIMITER before and after the create trigger statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469784/creating-trigger-for-table-in-mysql-database-syntax-error)

Comment: I'm looking at the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) and are you giving SQL to alter the table?  These commands are from the MySql console?

Comment: It wasn't intended to be a complete statement, i added the missing part.

Comment: ok created a dummy trigger, but can't get the syntax for the kind of trigger which you describe above.

Comment: I seem to be missing something here. You need another table for the hashes ?

Comment: the same table should have newsgroup (just a string, 80 chars or so) and hash, so that the hash can be set as unique.

Comment: Why are you trying to insert into a table named 'hash' then? Also if your string is ~80 chars - just make it UNIQUE. The hash would be necessary for long texts (maybe > 500 or something).